# Save standard way to declare a singleton

Tags: objective-c, singleton, xcode4.2

```
+ (GrabClass *)grab{
    static GrabClass * ngrab = nil;

        if (ngrab==nil)
        {
            ngrab=[[GrabClass alloc]init];
        }


    return grab;
}
```

I used many singletons in my program. If I do it like that, however there is a chance that the grab method is called by different threads at the same time.

How to avoid it?

My current solution is to do:

```
+ (GrabClass *)grab{
    static GrabClass * ngrab = nil;
    [Tools DoSomethingWithSynchronize:^{
        if (ngrab==nil)
        {
            ngrab=[[GrabClass alloc]init];
        }
    }];

    return grab;
}
```

Where

```
+(void)DoSomethingWithSynchronize:(void (^)())block
{
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        [self singleton].lockToMakeSureThatOnlyOneThreadAccessThis=[NSThread currentThread];
        [self breakIfLock]; //should not be called
        block();
        [self singleton].lockToMakeSureThatOnlyOneThreadAccessThis=nil;
    }
}
```

Seems like overkill. I wonder if there's a better standard solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread safe instantiation of a singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199106/thread-safe-instantiation-of-a-singleton)

Comment: and pretty much the definitive SO post on ObjC singletons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like

Comment: How do you find all those duplicates anyway? +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a very good example and documentation [here](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/).

You can just use `@synchronized(self)` to synchronize the operations.