# static method objective c - init once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, alloc

I want to class that should be initialized only once and returns some value which was computed the first time. Is below the right approach ?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userAgent;

@implementation UserAgent
@synthesize userAgent = _userAgent;


+ (NSString *) userAgentString
{
    UserAgent *thisClass;
    if(self == nil)
    {
        thisClass = [[UserAgent alloc] init];
    }

    if (thisClass.userAgent == nil)
    {
        return @"not initialized";
    }

    return thisClass.userAgent;
}
```

Comment: Search for information on singleton's for a good example of how to do this.

Comment: add static before UserAgent *thisClass and you should be fine. `static UserAgent *thisClass;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread safe instantiation of a singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199106/thread-safe-instantiation-of-a-singleton)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

1. `thisClass` is a local variable. This means, the value will be reset (to garbage) everytime `+userAgentString` is called. At least make it `static`.
2. `self`'s meaning is not what you expect inside a class method. Do you mean `thisClass`?
3. Even with the above fixes, the method isn't thread-safe, which may or may not be okay.

See [Create singleton using GCD's dispatch_once in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c) and [Singleton in iOS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796529/singleton-in-ios-5) as examples to properly construct a *singleton*.

Comment: @i_raqz: which is the same as the first answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796529/singleton-in-ios-5.

Answer (score 0):

A couple changes.  First, `thisClass` should be static.  Second, you don't have a `self` pointer in a static method, so you should be using `thisClass` there.  Like so:

```
+ (NSString *) userAgentString
{
    static UserAgent *thisClass;
    if(thisClass == nil)
    {
        thisClass = [[UserAgent alloc] init];
    }

    if (thisClass.userAgent == nil)
    {
        return @"not initialized";
    }

    return thisClass.userAgent;
}
```

Also, a better approach might be to use a Singleton, as mentioned by a commenter.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

This worked..Thanks @Inafziger