# Code execution stops on using thread safe Singleton initialization code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, singleton

To make use of global variables and methods I implemented Singleton as a healthy coding practice. I followed [Apple documents](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/), [john wordsworth blog](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/) before implementing it. In the first, I did not make my singleton thread safe and I implemented this method along with all other mentioned in the blog and Apple document.

```
+ (SingletonClass *)sharedManager 
{
  static SingletonClass *sharedManager = nil;
  if (sharedManager == nil) {
    sharedManager = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
}
  return sharedManager;
}
```

After that to make Singleton thread safe I made changes to `+ (SingletonClass *)sharedManager` class like this and my app stops launching. I put break points and observed `dispatch_once` gets called twice and then code stops executing further.

```
+(SingletonClass *)sharedManager
{
  static SingletonClass *sharedManager = nil;
  if (sharedManager !=nil)
  {
    return sharedManager;
  }
  static dispatch_once_t pred;       
  dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    sharedManager = [SingletonClass alloc];
    sharedManager=[sharedManager init];
});

     return sharedManager;
}
```

If i remove this thread safe code snippet and revert back to previous code it works fine and code gets executed.

Please note that I also looked at the [bbum's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199106/thread-safe-instantiation-of-a-singleton) in which he has mentioned possible deadlock situation before asking question but I am not able to figure out the issue. Any explanation or solution will be helpful for me. Thanks.

> Edit 1:

In case someone wants to look at the complete code, I have created [**gist**](https://gist.github.com/4473361) for that. Please follow there. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's consider what happens if two threads call second version of `sharedManager` almost simultaneously.

Thread 1 calls first.  It checks `sharedManager !=nil`, which is false, so it goes on to the `dispatch_once`.  In the `dispatch_once` block, it executes `[SingletonClass alloc]` and stores the result in `sharedManager`.

Now, before thread 1 continues on to the next line, thread 2 comes along and calls `sharedManager`.  Thread 2 checks `sharedManager !=nil`, which is now true.  So it returns `sharedManager`, and the caller then tries to use `sharedManager`.  But at this time, `sharedManager` hasn't been fully initialized yet.  That's bad.

You cannot set `sharedManager` until you have a **fully initialized** object to set it to.  Also (as borrrden pointed out), you don't need the `sharedManager !=nil` check at the top, because `dispatch_once` is very efficient anyway.

```
+ (SingletonClass *)sharedManager {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static SingletonClass *sharedManager;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedManager = [[SingletonClass alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedManager;
}
```

Now, I've looked at your gist and your problem is here:

```
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone*)zone {
    return [[self sharedManager] retain];
}
```

Your `+[SingletonClass sharedManager]` method calls `+[SingletonClass alloc]` in the `dispatch_once` block.  Since you don't override `alloc`, `+[SingletonClass alloc]` calls `+[SingletonClass allocWithZone:NULL]`.  And `+[SingletonClass allocWithZone:]` method calls `+[SingletonClass sharedManager]`.  On this second call to `sharedManager`, your program hangs in `dispatch_once`, because you're still inside the first call to `dispatch_once`.

The simplest fix is to remove your implementation of `allocWithZone:`.  Just document that `sharedManager` is the only supported way to get an instance of `SingletonClass` and move on.

If you want to be obtuse and make `[[SingletonClass alloc] init]` return the singleton, even if you do it repeatedly, it's complicated.  Don't try to override `alloc` or `allocWithZone:`.  Do this:

```
static SingletonClass *sharedManager; // outside of any method

+ (SingletonClass *)sharedManager {
    return sharedManager ? sharedManager : [[SingletonClass alloc] init];
}

- (id)init {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        if (self = [super init]) {
            // initialization here...
            sharedManager = self;
        }
    });
    self = sharedManager;
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation of code.. I wrote `sharedManager = [[SingletonClass alloc] init];` in the first then only split it into two lines as per bbum's answer I have mentioned. You are right problem is somewhere else. Also posted a link of full code if someone wants to look in full code.

Comment: Great.. Working now.. Thanks for your time to look into full code. Accepting as an answer..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the check on the top, get rid of the `if` statement.  The `dispatch_once` guarantees that the block will only be executed once in the lifetime of the application so the first check is redundant.

More Info:
http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.jp/2011/04/singletons-your-doing-them-wrong.html

Comment: Worth adding: dispatch_once is fast. At least as fast as the "nil" check. The difference is that someone wrote some very clever code to make it thread safe, which the check for "nil" isn't. In the worst case, sharedSingleton could return nil with the code as written (if a second call comes in while sharedSingleton is still nil just before it is assigned, the running dispatch_once finishes, dispatch_once does nothing because the first dispatch_once has finished, and because sharedSingleton is not volatile the compiler assumes it is still nil and returns nil.