# Is this method of initializing singleton thread safe?

Tags: ios, thread-safety

this is a scope of code in our project, I think it is not thread-safe, because the scope

```
if(sharedHelper)
    return sharedHelper;
```

will cause problem, but I am not sure, could any one help me?

```
+(id) sharedHelper
{
static MyHelper *sharedHelper = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

if(sharedHelper)
    return sharedHelper;

dispatch_once(&onceToken,^{

    sharedHelper = [[self alloc] init];
});

return sharedHelper;
}
```

Comment: You can omit the `if(sharedHelper) return sharedHelper;` business (since `dispatch_once`, as the name suggests, only calls the block once in the lifetime of the app), but regardless, it looks fine to me. What problem do you suspect?

Comment: Check this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2202304/2315974

Comment: the second may use the sharedHelper while the first thread has not completed the initialization of it. @Mar0ux

Comment: @haibarahu No it won't. `dispatch_once` has synchronized access on `onceToken`, so until the first thread has finished running the block, the second won't proceed.

Comment: yes, I know this.But the second thread will not access the code of dispatch_once, it access the scope "if(sharedHelper) return sharedHelper;".@Mar0ux

Comment: @haibarahu that's right, that's why you should remove that check. interesting read on why that check doesn't work as you expect it to: http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf

Comment: @haibarahu Oh I see I said `regardless` in my original comment, which could have been misleading. Since I can't edit it now, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that `if` block might cause problems. Here's why ([source](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf)):

This line

```
[[MyHelper alloc] init];
```

is actually made up of three steps:

1. Allocate memory
2. Construct object into allocated memory
3. Point static variable to the allocated memory address

Now, you would expect these things to happen in order from 1-3. But, in certain cases, compiler *may* reorder the instructions such that step 3 happens before step 2 -

```
sharedHelper = // Step 3
    operator new(sizeof(MyHelper)); // Step 1
new (sharedHelper) MyHelper; // Step 2
```

Now, consider this scenario: Thread 1 executes steps 1 and 3 and is suspended. So the static variable points to a memory location that has not yet been initialized. Now, if thread 2 checks `if(sharedHelper)`, it finds a non-NULL address, and returns that address. But wait, this address is not initialized yet - and BAM, you have a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Also check this related [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202304/2315974).

Comment: What you said, plus on a multi-core system, different threads are not guaranteed to see write operations in the same order. So even if the code does everything in the "right" order, another thread might not see things in the same way. dispatch_once does all the necessary read/write barriers to make everything work correctly. And after the first call to dispatch_once (and calls happening at the same time which must block), dispatch_once is _fast_ so there is absolutely no point checking a different condition.